# How to vertically flip data in BQL?

Tags: sql, birt

Title. For example, I have below data:

```
Key1  Key2   Cost   Qty_LIFO    Date    
Red   A      2      19          1/4/2018
Red   A      3      18          1/3/2018
Red   C      4      7           1/2/2018
Red   A      5      16          1/1/2018    
Blu   B      21     91          1/4/2018
Blu   B      31     81          1/3/2018
Blu   D      41     70          1/2/2018
Blu   D      51     60          1/1/2018
```

The goal is to transform the data to look like below. Flip the quantity column, while also taking into account the Keys/categories

```
Key1  Key2   Cost   Qty_FIFO    Date    
Red   A      2      16          1/4/2018
Red   A      3      18          1/3/2018
Red   C      4      7           1/2/2018
Red   A      5      19          1/1/2018    
Blu   B      21     81          1/4/2018
Blu   B      31     91          1/3/2018
Blu   D      41     60          1/2/2018
Blu   D      51     70          1/1/2018
```

or like this (Qty_FIFO is flipped and added to the first example at the top):

```
Key1  Key2   Cost   Qty_LIFO    Qty_FIFO    Date    
Red   A      2      19          16          1/4/2018
Red   A      3      18          18          1/3/2018
Red   C      4      7           7           1/2/2018
Red   A      5      16          19          1/1/2018    
Blu   B      21     91          81          1/4/2018
Blu   B      31     81          91          1/3/2018
Blu   D      41     70          60          1/2/2018
Blu   D      51     60          70          1/1/2018
```

The purpose of this is to calculate LIFO and FIFO costs.

I need to take Qty_LIFO column (which is sorted by date, descending), flip it vertically (so the data becomes Date ASC), and re-add it to the table without changing the sorting of the Costs column.

Basically, I need to pair the newest Cost data with the oldest Qty data and continue from there.

Comment: What rdbms you are using?

Comment: Are you actually looking to modify the data in the table, or just select the data in this format?

Comment: @DeanOC:  Modify?  I suppose?   I need to take Qty_LIFO column (which is sorted by date, descending),   Flip it vertically (so the data becomes Date ASC),  and re-add it to the table without changing the sorting of the Costs column. 

Basically, I need to pair the newest Cost data with the oldest Qty data and continue from there.

Comment: @dwir182: I'm using Birst. its a cloud based reporting platform. It uses a language called BQL which is mostly the same as SQL. –

Comment: If it's *mostly the same as SQL*, you can just use an ORDER BY. You can specify the sort order of individual columns, as in `ORDER BY COL_A DESC, COL_B DESC, COL_C ASC, COL_D DESC`.

Comment: I don't see your problem here.. Just do @KenWhite say and it's your solution and when you need cumulative do `Window Function` but i don't know if `bql` have that. [You can see this as example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=583e6899451b2afabef87c0328c90f53)

Comment: @KenWhite,   it didn't work. Seems the order by function in Birst is more for the dashboards/displays rather than something that works in the script/view.

I've edited my post to show more data, where I also need to account for categories.

Comment: Then I guess you should remove the SQL tag and instead add one for what you're actually working with instead. If SQL doesn't work, you're not asking a SQL question.

Comment: 1. can you please provide the BQL you are currently using (add it into the question).  2. aren't LIFO and FIFO are the results of calculations?  You probably need to change from a LIFO calculation to a FIFO calculation. "Flipping data" in just that one column isn't something you can achieve by using an `order by` clause by the way.

Comment: @KenWhite, i tried adding the correct tag before I posted this but apparently I need a minimum 550 rep or something to create the tags: bql ; birst

SQL is the closest currently existing tag.

Comment: @Used_By_Already,  I have yet to create a bql statement for this. So I don't have one that I can post.   Closest thing to it that I have is just a simple SELECT statement pulling for the 5 columns in the top example.. Yes, LIFO/FIFO are the results of a calculation however my question is the precursor to it.  I can calculate LIFO just from pulling the data however to calculate FIFO, I need that one column flipped somehow.  I unfortunately don't have access to the application (or a developer of it) which the users used previously to calculate for FIFO so I have to recreate it from scratch..

Comment: do you know, or can you find out what "window functions" BQL supports? in particular `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, which only works if you have access to `row_number()`

```
CREATE TABLE existing_qry(
   Key1     VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
  ,Key2     VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,Cost     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Qty_LIFO INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Date     DATE  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Red','A',2,19,'1/4/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Red','A',3,18,'1/3/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Red','C',4,7,'1/2/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Red','A',5,16,'1/1/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Blu','B',21,91,'1/4/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Blu','B',31,81,'1/3/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Blu','D',41,70,'1/2/2018');
INSERT INTO existing_qry(Key1,Key2,Cost,Qty_LIFO,Date) VALUES ('Blu','D',51,60,'1/1/2018');

with cte as (
    select 
            * 
        , row_number() over(partition by key1 order by date ASC) rn_asc
        , row_number() over(partition by key1 order by date DESC) rn_desc
    from existing_qry
    )
select
    t.Key1, t.Key2, t.Cost, t.Qty_LIFO, flip.Qty_LIFO as Qty_FIFO, t.Date, t.rn_asc, t.rn_desc
from cte as t
inner join cte as flip on t.key1 = flip.key1 and t.rn_asc = flip.rn_desc
```

It calculates 2 numbers for each row in opposite date order, then aligns rows by requiring these to be equal through a self join. This has the impact of reversing the LIFO numbers (or "flipping" that column).

```
       Key1   Key2   Cost   Qty_LIFO   Qty_FIFO          Date           rn_asc   rn_desc  
 ---- ------ ------ ------ ---------- ---------- --------------------- -------- --------- 
   1   Blu    B        21         91         60   04.01.2018 00:00:00        4         1  
   2   Blu    B        31         81         70   03.01.2018 00:00:00        3         2  
   3   Blu    D        41         70         81   02.01.2018 00:00:00        2         3  
   4   Blu    D        51         60         91   01.01.2018 00:00:00        1         4  
   5   Red    A         2         19         16   04.01.2018 00:00:00        4         1  
   6   Red    A         3         18          7   03.01.2018 00:00:00        3         2  
   7   Red    C         4          7         18   02.01.2018 00:00:00        2         3  
   8   Red    A         5         16         19   01.01.2018 00:00:00        1         4
```

https://rextester.com/LQBVD29253

Comment: Thanks for the answer however BQL barely has any advanced functions so no windows functions at all possible.  There is a sort of manual/Help guide for BQL however there's no point in providing the site as it requires a license and a login.